# Fee for Recommendation letters?

Tags: recommendation-letter, fees

My college demands a fee (equivalent to $10) from the students for every LOR that the student asks for. The fee goes to the college authorities and not to the professors themselves.

Is this a malpractice? I already wrote a complaint to principal/dean and he said that this is how it works.

What can I do about it, even my fellow classmates are exhausted paying so many fees since we are all applying to multiple colleges for admissions to future courses?

**EDIT:** I asked my dean based on the suggestion of the answer below (by Maarten Buis) and the reply stated that this is indeed an act to limit the applications that a student makes, so that the professors aren't burdened to write recommendations for students who apply to various institutions just for the sake of it/ a place where the said student would have no chance but still applies.

Comment: Which country is this in? Customs may vary.

Comment: A new low in academia...

Comment: @henning Is it alright for me to not tell the country's name? Since none of the other institutions in the country have this custom (I asked my colleagues from various places to verify this claim and they confirmed), it would just tarnish the image of my nation.

Comment: @mnuizhre of course. I'm just asking because it may help elicit useful answers. Regarding the image of your country, if it's just an outlier institution, there's no concern.

Comment: I wonder if it is just a hold over from the time in which staff people (secretaries) had to get involved in preparing such letters and getting them out. Or perhaps that is still the custom. I paid one of the staff to type my math thesis in the days before personal computers.

Comment: Imho it's particularly ridiculous that the price is for every letter, since usually once a letter is written for a student the others are just copies of the same letter. So there's zero justification for asking a fee for every different college the students applies for, it's almost always the same letter. Additionally the time spent by the professor writing these should obviously be already factored in the college fees: what's next, they're going to ask a fee for every question asked by the student to the professor, every correction, every hour of supervision... ??

Comment: Could you at least provide the geographic region of your country? Say "Western Europe", "South-east Asia", etc.

Comment: This is reminiscent to me of my school charging $0.05 per page printed, though on a more egregious scale. $0.05 per page is totally negligible for the school, and likely $10 is too - it's more about trying to force students to think twice before acting. Now, in my humble opinion a fee for LORs is unethical, but that's besides the point.

Comment: As if students with access to means and capital won't be willing to spend, potentially hundreds or more, for the chance to "shoot their shot". This policy really is just saying "if you are middle or lower class please be careful about how many letters of recommendation you ask"

Comment: @mnuizhre Can you please tell in which country this is happening?

Comment: I had to consider for some time whether to reveal the country's name over here or not, but since there is some correlation (which maybe I don't understand) thta exists and would maybe provide some useful info for me or others, I shall just mention it. It's India.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Malpractice has legal meaning that does not seem to apply here. So I will interpret your question as "is this wrong". After all, this is not the place to get legal advice.

Given the information you have given us, this seems to be a policy by the institution, and not one that professor invented themself, nor does that professor benefit from it. So the professor is not doing anything wrong. Professors are powerful, but even they have to bow to university policy.

There are possible justifications for such a fee. The time spent on writing such a letter is time that cannot be spent on other things, so there is a real cost the institution incurs for giving the student that service. However, given the small size of the fee, this sounds more to me like a policy to put up a small barrier to prevent overuse rather than a policy to get some money. Maybe, this was a reaction to too many students asking too many LORs. Maybe something like: lets ask all faculty members to write a LOR, and I will pick the two best ones. If many students do that, then the university needs to react, for example adding a small fee. I don't know if this applies to your university, but there are situations where such a fee may be justified.

That is the real answer I can give you: find out why they have that policy. It is hard to argue against a policy if you don't know why it is there. Maybe, they actually had a good reason, and you don't want to argue against it anymore. That would also be a good outcome.

Comment: $10 could be a less insignificant value in another country.

Comment: Re "Professors are powerful, but even they have to bow to university policy": I bet you they can write a LOR for  free as a favor. Now *that* may be a "malpractice" like any other favorable treatment of specific students, depending on the circumstances.

Comment: -1 for "there are situations where such a fee may be justified". This is totally unacceptable money-grabbing behaviour from any university under any and all circumstances. A failure of their basic duty to their students.

Comment: @JackAidley I don't think it is money-grabbing behaviour; it probably costs the university more to collect those fees (the prof has to collect it hand it to a secretary who needs to add it to an account, which needs to be checked, ...). I believe the edit by the OP that this is policy is designed to influence the student's behaviour. You can argue whether the policy is effective, whether the costs to the students outweight the benefits to the institution, whether the problem it is supposed to solve even exists. In all likelihood we would agree. ...

Comment: ... However treating universities like moneygrabbing supervillains is not helpful and most of the time not true. A policy has a goal. Once you know the goal, you can start a meaningful discussion with the university. Treating it as the enemy will get you nowhere. Whenever dealing with a university keep Hanlon's razor in mind: never attribute to malice that which is adequately explained by stupidity

Comment: @MaartenBuis OP did not say how the fee was collected, but I assumed (without proof) that the university reduced the transaction cost to almost nothing.  Fee collection does not necessarily require the professor's effort.

Comment: @emory the main cost involved is not the Prof but all the administration. Since this is an official policy, any money has to probably jump through many bureaucratic hoops. There are good reasons for that: there is money coming from a person who is in a dependent position. The rules are often there to prevent abuse.

Comment: @MaartenBuis It is really so different than my experience as a student that I am struggling to understand.  I just politely asked my professors, gave them my resume, and self-addressed, self-stamped envelopes.  There was nowhere for the university to insert itself and extract a fee.  But I figure many students today are interacting with their prof online and not in person.  So they can't just hand them a SASE.  OTH I understand most universities want referees to use an online portal to fill out their reference so the SASE is a thing of the past.  I just don't know how it works anymore.

Comment: @MaartenBuis Good advice, and it applies equally to (nearly?) all other situations too.

Comment: @emory it is a difficult concept evem for us to wrap our heads around. Since, no other institution that any of us ever have attended has asked for such a fee.

Comment: @mnuizhre My question is thus:  what would happen if you gave your prof a SASE?  Maybe the institution you are applying to has a portal for referees.  What would happen if you gave your prof the portal details.  Would your prof verify your fee payment, trust you paid, or not care.  Does the fee provide any service (like the university reminds the prof to be mindful of deadlines, etc)?

Comment: No nothing of that sort. I fill a form, make the payment to the office (note again, this doesn't go to the professors themselves), get the receipt and the professor shall then send my LoR to the institution where I am applying. The LoRs are already ready even before the payment is made, the rule is that it can't be sent out without paying the required sum.

Answer (score 1):

The policy at face seems perfectly reasonable to prevent some [Tragedy of the Commons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tragedy_of_the_commons), though in modern times, professors have been largely free to write or reject per-student (ie. why would they write a letter for a student who they are sure does not understand a subject to work with their peers? or why would they not write a letter for a promising student who added to their class? - surely they *must* be free to write or not write for either case if asked!)

However, without strong controls I believe this leads to some trouble-
The monetary fee is insignificant in comparison to the cost of attendance, but the process provides a novel way for the university to directly track some details of the process surrounding letters of recommendation.

Simply the knowledge that different counts of LOR are sent by professors could affect them personally (are they sending enough? too many?) or worse, financial information and speculative success information about students involved is no business of the university. (ie. is 15 letters too many? cheaper than a US physics text!)

Conversely (perhaps?), whether the payment is accepted shows information to a student whether a professor did write a LOR, while this information may not otherwise be known. (is this desirable? it's a break from the norm, but perhaps not a bad one)